# How to auto-insert a sequence number in a Webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

Is there a way to add a Webform field that serves a unique sequence number? Hopefully the number can be sequentially counted for each Webform type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module for this: [Webform Serial number](https://drupal.org/project/webform_serial):
https://drupal.org/project/webform_serial

> This module provides an auto-incrementing number field for webforms.